# Rails Production Enviornment errors submit via email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app in production that as designed when an exception is raised, I get the 500 page "Something went wrong".  When this happens, an employee will usually call me right away and tell me that an error occurred but this is not always the case.  Sometimes I won't know about the error in production until later that day or longer.

What I'd like to do is set up my production environment to where when an exception/error is raised it displays and error page, but sends me an email in the background.

I've done some research and I see there's AirBrake, but I'm really looking to build/implement my own solution instead of paying for a 3rd-party service.

Can anyone suggest a gem or snippet of code that emails when an error/exception is raised and/or gives the end-user the option to submit the error from the 500 page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [exception notification](http://rubygems.org/gems/exception_notification) does exactly this.

You might also be interested in [errbit](https://github.com/errbit/errbit). It implements the same api as airbrake - in a nutshell you'd be hosting your own version of airbrake.

Comment: We've discovered squash recently, from Square. My team and I like it better than errbit: http://squash.io/

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions.  I'm going to check out the exception_notification and also look at Squash as a more robust solution.  Ideally I'd like to keep it simple so the exception_notification gem will probably be best to start out with, but moving to errbit or Squash will be my long-term plan.  My goal really is to be notified of exceptions/errors instantly and before the employees have a chance to drop the ball on it.  I really want to be proactive here.